# sed change line error message

Tags: sed, edit

I have a config file I need to change (again) and the line is

```
set wrapper_code=C:\windows\drivers\cache
```

I need to change it to

```
set wrapper_code=/home/harry/solo/run
```

I wrote

```
cat Proxy.bat | sed -i.bk -e 's/\(^set wrapper_home\=\).*/\/home/'1${dbuser}'/gateway/service\'  Proxy.bat
```

I get an error message

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unknown option to `s'
```

What is wrong with my code string

Comment: Whoever is marking my questions with a negative comment. It seens a bit unfair to do so because this forum is suppose to be about questions. To have to show that I have done research in the opening text and to tell me to keep the question to the point is confusing. You want me to tell you everything I did before posting my question?

Comment: I thought this site is suppose to be about help and not a grading system on how well a question if formed formulated or researched before posting a simular question. The site is already geared to force research so why would think that a person would not have looked before posting a question? You can't get around it because even as a question is being writen out the right there are searches. So it is tyrencal to mark a question with a negative mark and you have no idea what search the person has done.

Comment: Suggestion, make training videos available for everyone to watch on every command that there is and then only allow questions after they have completed all the training videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `/` as the pattern separator is `sed`, you have to escape the slashes in the strings (paths). To avoid it, use a different separator:

```
sed -i.bk -e 's%\^set wrapper_code=C:\\windows\\drivers\\cache%set wrapper_code=/home/harry/solo/run%'  Proxy.bat
```

You also have to escape backslashes, as they have a special meaning in `sed`.

The `cat` part is useless.

Comment: I tried the line and it does not edit the line in the file. I am using the line in a shell script so the cat part is necessary? If you could show me how to use the sed without the cat that would help also.

Comment: @user1794918: Just give the filename as an argument to `sed`.

Comment: But I thought that is what the cat | is for to open the stream for the file to be passed to sed.

Comment: @user1794918: `cat` is an external program. To run it, a new process must be started, which takes time. Redirection (`<`) can be used to open the stream.

Comment: Typically, using `cat` to pipe data to `sed` is merely useless, but in this case it is catastrophic because of the use of `-i`.  The `-i` causes `sed` to completely ignore the data fed to it by `cat` and instead modify a file named `-`.  Useless use of cat should be avoided.  As should the `-i` option to sed.